# How to add a property at runtime in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this code which works:

```
 if ((<any>this.router).userIntendedRedirectRoute) {
        this.router.navigate((<any>this.router).userIntendedRedirectRoute);
    } else {
        this.router.navigateBack(); 
    }
```

Basically, in earlier code, I add a property to the router, and then assign it a value.

Then later, I retrieve that value.

It works, but it seems crude to be casting to any multiple times.

The problem that I am trying to solve is that the router comes from a framework, and I cannot change the source directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get property value via square brackets and property name:

```
this.router["userIntendedRedirectRoute"]
```

Comment: I really like this answer.  Using square brackets clearly shows that this is a dynamic property.  In other words, the developer is opting out of type-checking for this property.  Note however, that this brings up a new issue in that the compiler flags it as an "Implicity any" error. Fortunately, the TS Team created a `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` flag which allows this to be used without generating an error.

Comment: +1 FWIW `Using square brackets clearly shows that this is a dynamic property` is a known and supported concept

Comment: This works great with JSON Web Tokens that are created on the server, so many properties are created at runtime!Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `any`, you should define what the router is.

```
interface MyRouter {
    userIntendedRedirectRoute?: string;
    navigate(route: string);
    navigateBack();
}

if((<MyRouter>this.router).userIntendedRedirectRoute) {
    (<MyRouter>this.router).navigate((<MyRouter>this.router).userIntendedRedirectRoute);
} else {
    (<MyRouter>this.router).navigateBack();
}
```

You can also cast it onto a variable:

```
var myRouter: MyRouter = this.router;

if(myRouter.userIntendedRedirectRoute) {
    myRouter.navigate(myRouter.userIntendedRedirectRoute);
} else {
    myRouter.navigateBack();
}
```